# OpenMPI java bindings in Windows 10 Cygwin

Tags: java, cygwin, mpi, openmpi

I'm trying to get OpenMPI working on windows 10 with java bindings.  I've gotten OpenMPI working with cygwin, but I want to get the java bindings working on cygwin as well.  I've looked online but can't seem to find any good resources on how to get this working.  Does anyone know how to do this, or have a good source on how to do it?

I know normally you can find the ompi directory and use 
./configure --enable-mpi-java

But I can't seem to figure out how to find the correct directory/command with cygwin.  Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
There is no `Java` compiler as Cygwin package.

For this reason OpenMPI on Cygwin is only available with C and Fortran bindings.

If you need it, try a Virtual Machine with Linux installed